# Replace a string starting with a character

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace a user input with my own string, with the user's inputted message only having a known start character.

The user enters their input "@userinput" which will then change to

```
<a href="userinput"> userinput </a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my attempts can be seen below.

My attempts.
Code:

```
preg_match('#(?>\@)(\w*)#', $string, $matches);
foreach($matches as $row){
    $string = preg_replace('#(?>\@)(\w*)#', '<a href="'.$row.'"> '. $row . "</a>", $string);
}
```

OTHER ATTEMPT

```
 $string = preg_replace('#\@(.*)#', '<b><a href="=$1"=> @$1 </a></b>', $string);
```

Comment: Maybe you just need `$string = preg_replace('#@(\w+)#', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);`?

Comment: This doesn't work, furthermore this is down properly above using (.*) but if you have multiple instances of an @ or other text in between, it breaks.

Comment: [Looks working well enough](https://3v4l.org/Z0QMp) to me.

Comment: What specifically is the error you're getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```php
$atPosition = stripos($string, '@');
$substr = '';
if (stripos($string, '@') !== false) {
    $substr = substr($string, $atPosition + 1);
    $content = '<b><a href="'.$substr.'"> '.$substr.' </a></b>';
}

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to exclude space and `@`:

```
$string = preg_replace('#@([^\s@]+)#', '<b><a href="$1"> @$1 </a></b>', $string);
```